# Viewport shifted horizontally when textfield is focused

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile, sencha-touch-2

This is the issue I'm having when the textfield is focused in my Sencha Touch App

[image]

The textfield seems to be centered vertically and horizontally for some reason.

This is how it's supposed to look

[image]

Does anyone already have the same issue and solved it ?

**Update**

It does not happen all the time but does happen on any textfield that is not originally horizontally centered.

Does happen on Android sometimes as well (Chrome 26)

Comment: And how exactly is it supposed to look? We just see a TextBox that looks properly aligned...

Comment: I just added a screenshot of how it's supposed to look. The same but without the horizontal centering (so without the white margin on the right)

Comment: Do you have the page uploaded somewhere we can test? Strip the rest of app, leave just the problem page :)

Comment: @TDeBailleul By the way, try [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6918582/684932) approach. This might solve your problem. If it solve, let me know and I'll post as answer.

Comment: Your page is probably already too wide, and when the page is focused, the browser is just centering the focus on the device. The fb-root div is probably causing it as Facebook will dynamically generate content and put it in there, causing the page to be too wide.

Comment: Exactly. I fixed it easily by hiding the fb-root div after the app request is sent. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually the Facebook `<div>` that you need to have in your index.html, which during the app requests was causing this issue. Like @rdougan said, it was larger than the screen and therefore the field was horizontally and vertically centered.

To solve this issue, I just hide the Facebook `<div>` after the app request has been sent and show it whenever I need it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are seeing is (at least from the screenshots) iOS's Safari auto-zoom feature on input boxes. This "*phenomenon*" automatically centers/focuses an input box when it gains input focus.

This `<meta />` tag helps prevent that:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

What this `<meta />` tag above accomplishes is:

- *Rendering* the page at the device's screen width;
- Setting the zoom level at `1:1`;
- And fixing the **maximum** scale to be `1` (essentially *unscalable*).

If your page is *definite* optimized for mobile devices, then the above solution should work just fine.

---

Alternatively, in case you'd like to have *control* over which `<input />` control this happens to, use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and then, set each `<input />`'s `font-size` style to **at least** 16 pixels.

```
<input type="text" style="font-size: 16px;" />
```

This more compact `<meta />` tag simply says that the page *should* be initially presented at a `1:1` scale.

---

Here's a [test page](http://stage.esoland.net/_Test_/InputZoom.htm) (shortened: http://bit.ly/15GbxJa) that will demonstrate what you (hopefully) want to fix. This test page is using the second (alternate) method for more fine-grained control; you can take a look at the source code for reference.

Initial page display:

[image: Initial page display]

With and without auto-zoom respectively:

[image: Auto-zoom enabled]
[image: Auto-zoom disabled]

Comment: Sencha Touch apps already have the meta <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> So there is already no zoom.

Comment: Well, I guess that's that...but, can you place online a test page that demonstrates the same issue?

Comment: I tried but the bug only appears when I use the entire and I'm not allowed to publish that. But I found something though. I have a <div id="fb-root"></div> in my page and if I remove it, then the bug is gone...

Comment: Well, I guess this is where I draw the line =\. Unfortunately, I have never used Sencha Touch, and I thought that it may have been a page scaling issue; I'm sorry. If there's anything else I can do, please feel free to reply.

Comment: Giving you the bounty for the help and also because it might help other users. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @TDeBailleul! Hopefully the answer does help someone in the future. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting min-width on the parent element